# C# mongodb driver aggregation explain

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongodb-.net-driver

Is there a way using the C# mongodb driver to get an explain for a aggregation query?  What I specifically want is the execution time stat.

```
var redact = BsonDocument.Parse(redactJson);
var project = BsonDocument.Parse(projectJson);
var explain = BsonDocument.Parse(@"{explain: true}");

var pipeline =
            collection.Aggregate()
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(redact)
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(project)
                .AppendStage<BsonDocument>(explain)
```

Comment: The "explain" option of aggregate does not include execution time. See [Example Aggregate Method Explain Option](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#example-aggregate-method-explain-option). It only really shows index selection and "optimized" pipeline stages used. If you want the execution times you want [Database Profiling](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/), which is a completely different thing.

Comment: I don't think this is an exact duplicate. The question asks how to to do this from the C# driver. The question you referenced refers to Mongo shell and the jira feature was marked as fixed as show here [link](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504) Can you explain how you conclude this is an exact duplicate?

Comment: Real simple **1.** Aggregate explain does not return execution times. Check. **2.** The only way you are going to get it right now is by querying `system.profile`, which is also mentioned in the linked question. Dude, there is nothing C# specific here. If it was a matter of syntax for a paramter, then I would let it through. But since it simply cannot be done. I will not. Existing answers cover your possible outcomes. Exact duplicate.